# Symfony 4 | Wildcards: All requests with specific method to a specific action

Tags: symfony, routes, annotations

I am using Symfony 4 with annotations and I want to configure an action which gets all OPTIONS-requests to any route.

How I thought it could work:

```php
/**
 * @Route(".*", methods={"OPTIONS"})
 */
public function optionsRequestAction()
{
    // every request to any route should land here
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT: 
Thanks to Jakumi

The correct way would be:

```php
/**
 * @Route("{wildcard}", requirements={"wildcard": ".*"}, 
 *     methods={"OPTIONS"})
 */
public function optionsRequestAction()
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: `How I thought it could work` - and it doesn't? If it doesn't, what does the log tell you? Your question is incomplete.

Comment: `@Route("/{path}", method={"OPTIONS"}, requirements={"path":".*"})`